# C: linked list push segfault

Tags: c

I am trying to writing a function which can add new struct to the end of the linked list. while it always got Segmentation fault.

```
void
push(stk_t *stklist, info_t *gds)
{
    stk_t *current = stklist;

    if (current == NULL)
    {
        current->gds = (info_t *)malloc(sizeof(info_t));
        current->gds = gds;
        current->next = (stk_t *)malloc(sizeof(stk_t));
        current->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        while (current != NULL)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = (stk_t *)malloc(sizeof(stk_t));
        current->next->gds = (info_t *)malloc(sizeof(info_t));
        current->next->gds = gds;
        current->next->next = (stk_t *)malloc(sizeof(stk_t));
        current->next->next = NULL;
    }

}
```

And my structs

```
typedef struct{
    char name[NAME_SIZE];
    char aisle;
    int shelf;
    int weight;
    int price;
    int quantity;
} info_t;


typedef struct stk stk_t;

struct stk{
    info_t *gds;
    stk_t *next;
};
```

the aim of the function push() is to add the second argument to the end of the linked list.

Comment: Hint: when you do `current->gds = (info_t *)malloc(sizeof(info_t));`, what value does `current` have?

Comment: `if (current == NULL)
{
    current->gds` - dereferencing a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: @molbdnilo Oops, I broke your hint. Didn't see it when I posted, sorry.

Comment: Indeed all those four fields are using invalid `current` pointer. No matter whether the list exists or not, you still need to allocate memory for the struct, you should do that first and then either add it to the list or use it as the list pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code of `push()` is very wrong.

`gds` is allocated and immediately overwritten:

```
    current->gds = (info_t *)malloc(sizeof(info_t));
    current->gds = gds;
```

Even if `current` is `NULL`, it will be immediately dereferenced (which is most likely causes Segmentation Fault):

```
if (current == NULL)
{
    current->gds = (info_t *)malloc(sizeof(info_t));
```

Also, do not explicitly convert result of `malloc`.

---

If I understood what you're trying to do, push should look like this.

```
void
push(stk_t **stklist, info_t *gds)
{
    stk_t* current = *stklist;

    // Create & initialize new entry
    // gds is passed as parameter, so use it!
    stk_t* newstk = malloc(sizeof(stk_t));
    newstk->gds = gds;
    newstk->next = NULL;

    // No entries had been inserted, overwrite root pointer
    if(current == NULL) {
        *stklist = newstk;
        return;
    }

    // Find last entry that has available ->next
    while(current->next != NULL)
        current = current->next;

    current->next = newstk;
}

...

// Use it like this
stk_t* root = NULL;
push(&root, ...);
push(&root, ...);
push(&root, ...);
```

This is pretty idiomatic - keep pointer to a first entry, and for first entry overwrite pointer itself, for latter go to last entry and overwrite `next` in it. BTW, this is not *stack*, but simple *single-linked list*

For *stack* implementation will look like this:

```
void
push(stk_t **stklist, info_t *gds)
{
    stk_t* newstk = malloc(sizeof(stk_t));
    newstk->gds = gds;
    newstk->next = *stklist;

    // Push new entry on top of the stack
    *stklist = newstk;
}

info_t*
pop(stk_t **stklist) {
    stk_t* current = *stklist;
    info_t* gds;

    if(!current)
        return NULL;

    // Remove entry from top of the stack and
    // use next entry as new top
    *stklist = current->next;
    gds = current->gds;
    free(current);

    return gds;
}
```